# OpenXML Adding AutoFilter to document using SAX

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, sax

For some reason my code will not add the auto filter to the spreadsheet.  It generates fine however when opened the autofilter is not present.  Below is the relevant snippet from my method.  I attempt to append the autofilter to the worksheet and then use the xmlwriter to write to the document.

```
//create worksheet part, and add it to the sheets collection in workbook
WorksheetPart wsp = wbp.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
OpenXmlWriter writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(wsp);
var worksheet = new Worksheet();
worksheet.AppendChild<AutoFilter>(new AutoFilter() { Reference = "A:BA" });
writer.WriteStartElement(worksheet);
writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer myself. After writing the end of the sheetdata is when the autofilter must be written.

```
  writer.WriteEndElement(); //end of SheetData
  writer.WriteElement(new AutoFilter() { Reference = "A:BA" });
  writer.WriteEndElement(); //end of worksheet
  writer.Close();
```